# How to get type of action in onAthleteGridSave/onAthleteGridEdit in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid as follow

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<MaintenanceAthletesAthleteGridViewModel>()
.Name("Athletes")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:435px" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model => model.Id(a => a.ResourceId))
      .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
      .Create(create => create.Action("InsertAthlete", "Maintenance"))
      .Read(read => read.Action("AthletesMaintenanceAthleteGridAjax", "Maintenance"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateAthlete", "Maintenance").Data("onAthleteGridUpdate"))
      .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteAthlete", "Maintenance").Data("onAthleteGridUpdate"))
   )
.Events(events => events
                .Save("onAthleteGridSave")
                .Edit("onAthleteGridEdit")
        )
...
%>

function onRequestEnd(e)
{
    if (e.type == "insert" || e.type == "update" || e.type == "destroy") {
        $("#Athletes").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }
}

function onAthleteGridSave(e)
{            
    if (e.type == "insert")
    { ...}
}

function onAthleteGridEdit(e)
{            
    if (e.type == "insert")
    { ...}
}
```

But e.type in onAthleteGridSave(e) and onAthleteGridEdit(e) is undefined, while e.type in onRequestEnd(e) is ok. My question is how to find the type of action such as "insert" or "update" in e or anywhere else inside onAthleteGridSave/onAthleteGridEdit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are manipulating two objects `Grid` and a `DataSource in your Grid`. And both have there own set of events along with their parameters.

- Events fired by Grid [see here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events)
- Events fired by DataSource [see here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events)

Therefore what you received as parameters in RequestEnd of DataSource is not applicable for Save or Edit of your Grid.

Your need to change functions like this:

```
function onAthleteGridSave(e)
{            
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```